# Simple Javascript maths

Tags: javascript, math, negative-number

I'm trying to work with some maths, and I can't get a negative number to act as a positive number. I have these numbers in different variables;

```
330 3106 -2776
```

I need 330, 3106 and 2776 so I can do this statement (obviously they will be vars though!);

```
if((2776 + 330) == 3106){ 

}
```

Is there a shorthand or quick method I can use to do this inside of my if statement? Id rather not have to make more variables to do this...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Math.abs()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```
if((Math.abs(-2776) + 330) == 3106){ 
  //...
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I was after. Thanks Tomasz and every else who replied. I'll accept as soon as the website lets me (got to wait a few mins first!)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) on a number to ensure it's positive.

```
Math.abs(-123);  // 123

Math.abs(123);   // 123
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Math.abs()` method.

```
Math.abs(-2276) === 2276
```